# Using csv column names as parameter in R function

Tags: r, function, csv

I'm trying to write a function that will open some .csv files and preform several calculations on specific parts of those dataframes. I'm having trouble passing a column name as a parameter in the function, and I'm not sure why. So something like this (minimal working example, my function is more complex than this):

```
MyFunction <- function(file, columnname){
    data <- read.table(file,sep=",",header=TRUE);
    mean(data$columnname);
    }
```

I have a .csv in my desktop called "test.csv", and all it has in it is a column called "numbers" and the numbers 1:10. If I run either of these:

```
MyFunction("~/Desktop/test.csv",numbers)
MyFunction("~/Desktop/test.csv","numbers")
```

I get this error:

```
[1] NA
Warning message:
In mean.default(data$columnname) :
   argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

However, if I run this:

```
data <- read.table("~/Desktop/test.csv",sep=",",header=TRUE);
mean(data$numbers);
```

I get this:

```
[1] 5.5
```

... which is what I want.

I'm not sure how my function is different from doing it by hand here. I can use function parameters to find and open the file, but using the function parameter in the data$parameter seems to be causing an error. Why is this? What workaround is there?

Comment: You could just use bracket indexing instead of indexing by `$`. For example, get the column number with something like `Idx <- match(columnname,names(data))` and then `mean(data[,Idx])`.

Comment: I actually ended up using this, although both answers were very helpful!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
MyFunction <- function(file, columnname) {
    data <- read.csv(file)
    mean(data[[columnname]])
}
```

Note:

```
b <- "a"
DF <- data.frame(a = 1, b = 2)
DF$b
## [1] 2
DF[[b]]
## [1] 1
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you! Was my problem using read.table or $ or both?

Comment: $ is the problem.  See clarification just added.